# get the owner of a repository through the github API

Tags: git, github, github-api

I want to get some informations about github repositories using only their name. To do so, I build my url as `https://api.github.com/repos/:owner/<TheName>` But of course it doesn't work because I need the :owner field.
I found many ways to get different informations on the github api documentation page but none to get the owner. Is there any way to easily get it?

I'm developping this using Python3, if this could help in any ways.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible.

Example:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

-> owner is `spring-projects`

See button **Fork**, has 11572 + 1 = 11573 projects named `spring-boot` on GitHub, has 11573 owners.

Comment: I was more or less expecting this answer, thanks anyway, I'll find another way